# Permission denied when trying to run a compiled C file in Kali Nethunter on Nexus 6 even after trying chmod and sudo

Tags: android, c, linux

I have a Nexus 6 running Marshmallow 6.0.1 which I successfully installed Kali Nethunter 3.0 to.
***In the Nethunter Terminal:***
I have successfully compiled the Helloworld program that is written in C using the command: **gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld**.
But then when I try to run it in the terminal using the command: **./helloworld**, it just gives me permission denied. I tried all sorts of **chmod** and **sudo** but to no avail. I tried the **ls -l helloworld** command and it gives me: **-rw-rw----**, there are no x characters and they don't appear even after "chmod +x". The helloworld C file is on the sdcard (I have referred to it in the terminal using: "cd /sdcard/". Could the problem be that the sdcard has a "noexec" flag? If so, what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: "Could the problem be that the sdcard has a "noexec" flag?" - congratulations, you already know what the cause is.

Comment: Then how would I solve it? The internal storage has a root folder and inside the root folder is the sdcard folder. I can't create a folder outside the sd card (next to the root folder).

Comment: What do you mean with _all sorts of **chmod** and **sudo**?_  They cannot be as much as to being impossible to enumerate here.  Please extend.  By the way, knowing what kind of filesystem you have `helloworld` file in would be of interest, to see why you cannot make it executable.  By the way, the `noexec` flag you mention is preciselly to disallow executing code coming from the filesystem we are talking about.